# Tried to disable GUI now neither GUI or TEXT loads

Tags: command-line, server, gui

I am brand new to Ubuntu Server (or even having a server).  I installed Ubuntu Server, installed a GUI using `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` so that I can check for other software graphically.

After finding what I needed I wanted to boot to **tty** (command line) each time.  I have seen it mentioned to change a parameter to "text" but my grub file is "read only" and I wasn't sure how to gain root to edit that file.  I then typed `sudo apt-get remove lightdm` and seemed to have made a mistake.

The machine now shows Ubuntu and the loading circles but does nothing.

What have I done, and how do I get back to command line boot, with GUI option?

Comment: update:  I figured out how to get a command line up, and have re-installed lightdm.  That fixed the GUI being stuck loading.

I just have to figure out how to properly boot to TEXT, and how to edit the grub line.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "boot to Text", but to edit the grub file, you have to use 'cd' to get to /etc/default.  Once there, type 'sudo gedit grub' to edit the file and be able to save changes.

Comment: Please [edit] your question so it asks what you actually want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have root permissions to edit the grub file so it should alow you to write if you open with either:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub 

gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

depending on whether you want a to do the editing in command line. You want to change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
```

then save and go back to the terminal and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then you can reboot to test:

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  One error i was making was typing "cd.." instead of "cd .." :)  I have limited command line experience and I obviously get certain items wrong.

Next with your help I was about to get access to the file and save it.  Everything works perfectly now!  This is going to be an adventure I see.